# tidymodels Novel levels found in column

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am using `tidymodels` to create a Random Forrest prediction. I have test data that contains a new factor level not present in the training data which results in the error:

```
1: Novel levels found in column 'Siblings': '4'. The levels have been removed, and values have been coerced to 'NA'. 
2: There are new levels in a factor: NA 
> test_predict
Fehler: Objekt 'test_predict' nicht gefunden
```

I tried to include a `step_novel` and `step_dummy` on the "Siblings" column but this does not resolve the error. How should I deal with new factors not present in training data?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

data <-
  data.frame(
    Survived = as.factor(c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)),
    Siblings = as.factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,3)),
    Class = as.factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)),
    Embarked = as.factor(c("s","c","m","m","s","c","s","m","m","s","s","s","s","s","s","s")) 
  )

test <-
  data.frame(
    Siblings = as.factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,4)), #New factor level
    Class = as.factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)),
    Embarked = as.factor(c("s","c","m","m","s","c","s","m","m","s","s","s","s","s","s","s")) 
  )

#Model
rf_model <-
  rand_forest() %>%
  set_args(
    mtry = 3,
    trees = 1000,
    min_n = 15
  ) %>%
  set_engine("ranger", 
             importance = "impurity") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

#Recipe
data_recipe <- 
  recipe(Survived ~Siblings + Class + Embarked, data=data) %>%
  step_novel(Siblings) %>%
  step_dummy(Siblings)
#Workflow
rf_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(data_recipe) %>%
  add_model(rf_model)

final_model <- fit(rf_workflow, data)
final_model

test_predict <- predict(final_model, test)
test_predict
```

Comment: I would consider resetting the levels with `factor` and `levels` common in both i.e. probably `union` of both levels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you notice in the [documentation for `step_novel()`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_novel.html), it says:

> When fitting a model that can deal with new factor levels, consider using `workflows::add_recipe()` with `allow_novel_levels = TRUE` set in `hardhat::default_recipe_blueprint()`. This will allow your model to handle new levels at prediction time, instead of throwing warnings or errors.

So you want to do that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

data <-
  data.frame(
    Survived = as.factor(c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)),
    Siblings = as.factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,3)),
    Class = as.factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)),
    Embarked = as.factor(c("s","c","m","m","s","c","s","m","m","s","s","s","s","s","s","s")) 
  )

test <-
  data.frame(
    Siblings = as.factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,4)), #New factor level
    Class = as.factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)),
    Embarked = as.factor(c("s","c","m","m","s","c","s","m","m","s","s","s","s","s","s","s")) 
  )

#Model
rf_model <-
  rand_forest() %>%
  set_args(
    mtry = 3,
    trees = 1000,
    min_n = 15
  ) %>%
  set_engine("ranger", 
             importance = "impurity") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

#Recipe
data_recipe <- 
  recipe(Survived ~Siblings + Class + Embarked, data=data) %>%
  step_novel(Siblings) %>%
  step_dummy(Siblings)

#Workflow
rf_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(data_recipe, 
             blueprint = hardhat::default_recipe_blueprint(allow_novel_levels = TRUE)) %>%
  add_model(rf_model)

final_model <- fit(rf_workflow, data)
final_model
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: rand_forest()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 2 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> • step_novel()
#> • step_dummy()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Ranger result
#> 
#> Call:
#>  ranger::ranger(x = maybe_data_frame(x), y = y, mtry = min_cols(~3,      x), num.trees = ~1000, min.node.size = min_rows(~15, x),      importance = ~"impurity", num.threads = 1, verbose = FALSE,      seed = sample.int(10^5, 1), probability = TRUE) 
#> 
#> Type:                             Probability estimation 
#> Number of trees:                  1000 
#> Sample size:                      16 
#> Number of independent variables:  5 
#> Mtry:                             3 
#> Target node size:                 15 
#> Variable importance mode:         impurity 
#> Splitrule:                        gini 
#> OOB prediction error (Brier s.):  0.254242

test_predict <- predict(final_model, test)
test_predict
#> # A tibble: 16 x 1
#>    .pred_class
#>    <fct>      
#>  1 0          
#>  2 1          
#>  3 0          
#>  4 1          
#>  5 0          
#>  6 0          
#>  7 0          
#>  8 0          
#>  9 0          
#> 10 1          
#> 11 0          
#> 12 1          
#> 13 0          
#> 14 0          
#> 15 0          
#> 16 0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The workflows functions are very strict about factor levels and other aspects of the new data, ensuring that they match up with the training data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (and all your tutorials)! Would be nice to get a warning pointing this out when using `step_novel().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question- how to define this inside workflowsets?  In the creation of workflowsets, we  add recipe as a list.

Comment: @SaifKabirAsif you can [add options to a workflowset](https://workflowsets.tidymodels.org/reference/option_add.html); I recommend putting together a reprex and asking this on [RStudio Community](https://rstd.io/tidymodels-community) if you are having trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question:

We need to apply `step_novel` followed by `step_unknown`. As far as I understand from the documentation `step_novel` labels any new factors occurring in the data with "new". This can be used to easily identify such factors when the data is inspected after applying the recipe. `step_unknown` removes any such factors from the data and converts the values to NA when the model is applied:

```
data_recipe <- 
   recipe(Survived ~Siblings + Class + Embarked, data=data) %>%
   step_novel(Siblings) %>%
   step_unknown(Siblings)
```